Which $\kappa$-complete ideals I of $P(\kappa)$ make the quotient $P(\kappa)/I$ $\kappa^+$ complete?
Let $\kappa$ be a regular, uncountable cardinal. There exist no nonprincipal, $\kappa^+$-complete ideals of the Boolean algebra $P(\kappa)$. On the other hand, the ideal $I_{NS}$ of non-stationary sets (those in the complement of an order-closed, unbounded subset of $\kappa$) is an example of a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ideal. Furthermore, the quotient $P(\kappa)/I_{NS}$ is a $\kappa^+$-complete Boolean algebra, even though the quotient map is, of course, not a $\kappa^+$-complete homomorphism.
The infimum, mod $I_{NS}$, of a collection of $\kappa$ many subsets of $P(\kappa)$ is given by taking the diagonal intersection of these subsets. This is the case for any quotient $P(\kappa)/I$ where $I$ is the dual of a $\kappa$-complete normal filter $F$:
A filter $F$ on $\kappa$ is said to be normal if it is closed under diagonal intersections. That is, if $X_\alpha\in F$ for each $\alpha<\kappa$, then $\Delta_{\alpha<\kappa} X_\alpha=\{\alpha<\kappa|\alpha\in\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}X_\beta\}\in F$. If $F$ is $\kappa$-complete then this is equivalent to a version of Fodor's lemma: The dual $F$ of a $\kappa$-complete ideal $I$ is normal iff, for any $S_0\notin I$ and any $f:S_0\to\kappa$ such that $f(\alpha)<\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in S_0$, there exists some $S\subset S_0$ with $S\notin I$ such that $f|_S$ is constant.
A normal ideal is just the dual of a normal filter. It is known that any $\kappa$-complete normal ideal $I$ contains $I_{NS}$. Furthermore, any permutation $\sigma$ of $\kappa$ that maps some $S\notin I$ onto $\sigma(S)\in I_{NS}$ induces a $\kappa$-complete ideal $\sigma(I)$ with $\kappa^+$-complete quotient $P(\kappa)/I$, and $\sigma(I)$ is not normal since $\sigma(S)$ is a non-stationary set that is not in $\sigma(I)$.
My question is whether every nonprincipal, $\kappa$-complete ideal $I$ such that $P(\kappa)/I$ is $\kappa^+$-complete is necessarily induced by a normal ideal by permuting the elements of $\kappa$. In other words, is there always a normal ideal $I'$ and an isomorphism $\phi:P(\kappa)\to P(\kappa)$ such that $\phi(I)=I'$?
I've tried to approach the question in the special case where $I$ is maximal, in which case $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, and the dual filter $U$ is a ultrafilter. In this case, Theorem 10.20 of Jech's Set Theory proves that a function $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ exists such that the ideal generated by $f(I)$ is normal, $\kappa$-complete, and maximal. However, there is no guarantee that $f$ is a bijection.
Here, the function $f$ is the least element of a certain collection of functions in $\kappa^\kappa$ under the well-order, mod $U$, where $f<g$ iff $\{\alpha<\kappa|f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}\in U$. If we can find a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter $U$ such that $f$ is injective in some $S\in U$, and $|\kappa - f(S)|=|\kappa - S|$, that should be enough to ensure its equivalence mod $U$ to some permutation, as desired.
When $I$ is not maximal, the dual filter $F$ also induces a well-founded partial order on equivalence classes of functions, but it is not as well-behaved. For example, if $S,S'\notin I$ are disjoint and $S\cup S'=\kappa$, then the function $g$ given by $g(x)=0$ if $x\in S$, $g(x)=1$ if $x\in S'$, is not equivalent to the constant function $h$ given by $x\mapsto 1$, since $\{x<\kappa|g(x)=h(x)\}=S'\notin F$ and $g\not\equiv h$, while $\{x<\kappa|g(x)<h(x)\}=S\notin F$ and $g\not <h$. So I've had no luck with this approach.
I am also somewhat interested in the case where $\kappa$ is countable. Things are probably very different here since I don't believe normal filters exist in $\omega$. Any ideal is trivially $\omega$-complete and, if the ideal is maximal, then the quotient algebra is finite and therefore $\omega_1$-complete. Are there similar ideals that are not maximal? What cardinalities can the quotient algebra have? Thank you all for your help!
